# Cisco Router NAT does not work

Tags: networking, cisco, router, nat, ios

I have an active internet connection from provider on `festethernret0` and also have `vlan1`. I need to have an internet connection from `festethernret0` to my `vlan1`. I am doing it this way:

```
access-list 2 remark CCP_ACL Category=2
access-list 2 permit 10.0.1.0 0.0.0.255
interface Vlan1
 ip nat inside
 exit
interface FastEthernet0
 ip nat outside
 exit
ip nat inside source list 2 interface FastEthernet0 overload
```

This script is generated by Cisco Configuration Professional. I don't have internet connection on computer that is connected to `vlan1`. It pings router and other devices, but do internet connection. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an active internet connection from provider on `festethernret1` and also have `vlan1`. I need to have an internet connection from `festethernret1` to my `vlan1`.

If your Internet connection is on `FastEthernet 1`, then your config is wrong. Your config both applies `ip nat outside` on `FastEthernet 0`, and uses `FastEthernet 0` for the NAT overload configuration (`ip nat inside source list 2 interface FastEthernet0 overload`)

Comment: I edited my post. I have internet connection on `fastethernet0`

Comment: Ok, then that part of the configuration looks correct to me. We might have to see more of your configuration.